# Snyk for Talend package

Tags: talend, snyk

We are trying to scan a Talend package. Is there any documentation for scanning **talend packages** through **snyk**?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Snyk does not officially support Talend, but they do support Java through Maven. If you have those sorts of projects/ files existing, then you can scan them either with the IDE extension, CLI or UI.